# Changing skin on TN3 jQuery gallery

Tags: jquery, slideshow

I am trying to change the skin on the TN3 gallery but cannot get the tn3e skin to load? The slider is working no problem with the default skin tn3 so I know that everything is set up correctly? I have loaded to a local server (MAMP) but am still have the same problem. All that is displaying on the screen is 1/5 and nothing else. All of the folders are where the should be in the directory and I have searched everywhere for a solution. TI am still unable to resolve this no matter what I try to do.

Thank you very for any help, code is as follows:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www/w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <title>Slide Show</title>

  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="skins/tn3e/tn3e.css"></link>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tn3.min.js"></script>  

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
  var tn1 = $('.gallery').tn3({
  skinDir:"skins",
  skin:"tn3e",
  autoplay:true,
  delay:5000
  });
  });
</script>


</head>

<body>

<div class="tn3gallery">
    <div class="tn3e description">Picture of a pair of shoes!</div>
    <ul>

    <li>
      <h4>Shoes!</h4>
      <a href="images/1.jpg">
      <img src="images/thumbs/1.jpg" />
      </a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <h4>Cake</h4>
      <a href="images/2.jpg">
      <img src="images/thumbs/2.jpg" />
      </a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <h4>Groomsmen</h4>
      <a href="images/3.jpg">
      <img src="images/thumbs/3.jpg" />
      </a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <h4>Confetti!</h4>
      <a href="images/4.jpg">
      <img src="images/thumbs/4.jpg" />
      </a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <h4>Champagne!</h4>
      <a href="images/5.jpg">
      <img src="images/thumbs/5.jpg" />
      </a>
    </li>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the   set up wrong! It should have been  and not .  works no problem with the default gallery and this is what was throwing me. I don't think anyone else will have this problem as I must have changed it when I setting the files up. Just on the off chance though that anyone does encounter a problem with changing skins you may want to check that you have not done the same thing! Also I found along the way that if you are having a problem with getting the files to work locally you may want to change your browser or test online. Hope this helps someone having the frustrations I had!